# How to execute my python script automatically

Tags: python, excel, selenium-webdriver, execution

I had created one python script which will collect data from excel sheets and creating web requests automatically. There are 150 people in my organization.
I can install python to everyone's system and can teach them how to run them, but out of curiosity if they did any changes in script knowingly or unknowingly it will create a mess only

So, so far what i thought was
Tell them to drop their excels in certain common folder and whenever python in my system activated it check that common folder and if there's any excel it will do the work and end the script

for execute the python i took a help of task scheduler by scheduling task

Is there's any smart way to do this?
cause if any urgent request has to be raised and the user dropped that excel in folder but my next scheduler is only after 5 hrs, that will create issues

Comment: If this is on Windows, then I'd package it into an executable using something like `pyinstaller` and then schedule it to run using Task Scheduler. If this is *nix, then just add it as a cron job. Edit: I skipped over the part where you said task scheduler. Turn it into an exe with `pyinstaller` so they don't have to all have python installed.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to watch a folder for activity in python or a way to use an os scheduler to run python?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that excel sheets are the correct way to collect data? There's so many things that could go wrong with them vs having some sort of database to gather the required data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a script automatically then there are many ways to do it. Like you can use task manager (or cronjob if you use linux) on a machine that is on. You can also use all sorts of cloud services like "Function apps" on Azure or Lambda on AWS. However if you prefer to have the user run a script then you could create an executable as mentioned by picobit. On windows this will be a completely normal exe file.

To make a Python script into an executable file, you can use a third-party package such as PyInstaller (https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) or cx_Freeze (https://marcelotduarte.github.io/cx_Freeze/).
Here are the steps to do that:

1. Install PyInstaller or cx_Freeze by running `pip install pyinstaller`
   or `pip install cx-freeze` in your command line.
2. Navigate to the directory where your Python script is located.
3. Open a command prompt or terminal window in that directory.
4. Use PyInstaller or cx_Freeze to create an executable file by running
   the following commands:

   - For PyInstaller: `pyinstaller --onefile your_script.py`
   - For cx_Freeze: `cxfreeze your_script.py --target-dir dist`

   Replace `your_script.py` with the name of your Python script. This will create an executable file in a `dist` or `build` folder, depending on the package you used.
5. You can now run the executable file by double-clicking on it or
   running it from the command line. Like any other exe file.

You should read the documentation on the package you decide to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would have this python script run inside a container or any cloud service every 15 minuts and check against a cloud shared folder if there are files to process.

If it finds a file it processes it and moves it to another folder.